# Can the compiler optimize this snippet of code?

Tags: optimization, compiler-construction

Consider the following snippet of code:

```
for(i = 0; i<10; i++)
{
    int n = a[i];//first loop statement

    //other statements
}
```

Clearly, the complier will not hoist the first statement out of the loop. But would a compiler be able to hoist only the declaration of n above the loop? In other words, can a compiler optimize the above code too:

```
int n;

for(i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    n = a[i];//first loop statement
}
```

Comment: care to provide more details why you care?

Comment: you really think that a trick that comes to mind quite instantly couldn't be seen by a team building a compiler ?

Comment: Of course you assume that the declaration results in any code. Remember that hoisting applies to *executable code*. If a construct is not executable, there's nothing to hoist. An int variable declaration in C/C++, by itself, usually results in zero executable code. Also, your question is way too broad withou specifying what language it applies to, since in some languages presumably a declaration must do something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, most compilers will do this even at `-O0`:

```
~ $ cat t.c
volatile int v;

int a[10];

void f(void)
{
  int n;
  int i;
  for(i = 0; i < 10; i++) {

    n = a[i];
    v = n;
  }
}
~ $ clang -S -O0 t.c
~ $ cat t.s
…
_f:                                     ## @f
    .cfi_startproc
## BB#0:
    pushq   %rbp
Ltmp2:
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
Ltmp3:
    .cfi_offset %rbp, -16
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
Ltmp4:
    .cfi_def_cfa_register %rbp
    movl    $0, -8(%rbp)
LBB0_1:                                 ## =>This Inner Loop Header: Depth=1
    cmpl    $10, -8(%rbp)
    jge LBB0_4
## BB#2:                                ##   in Loop: Header=BB0_1 Depth=1
    movq    _v@GOTPCREL(%rip), %rax
    movq    _a@GOTPCREL(%rip), %rcx
    movslq  -8(%rbp), %rdx
    movl    (%rcx,%rdx,4), %esi
    movl    %esi, -4(%rbp)
    movl    -4(%rbp), %esi
    movl    %esi, (%rax)
## BB#3:                                ##   in Loop: Header=BB0_1 Depth=1
    movl    -8(%rbp), %eax
    addl    $1, %eax
    movl    %eax, -8(%rbp)
    jmp LBB0_1
LBB0_4:
    popq    %rbp
    ret
…
~ $
```

Note how, above, there are no instructions inside the body of the loop to reserve `n`. Instead the same stack slot `-4(%rbp)` is seamlessly reused. If I compiled with the slightest level of optimization, there wouldn't even be a stack slot for `n`: a register would be enough to hold its value for the short time span it has:

```
~ $ clang -S -O1 t.c
~ $ cat t.s
…
_f:                                     ## @f
    .cfi_startproc
## BB#0:
    pushq   %rbp
Ltmp2:
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
Ltmp3:
    .cfi_offset %rbp, -16
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
Ltmp4:
    .cfi_def_cfa_register %rbp
    xorl    %eax, %eax
    movq    _a@GOTPCREL(%rip), %rcx
    movq    _v@GOTPCREL(%rip), %rdx
    .align  4, 0x90
LBB0_1:                                 ## =>This Inner Loop Header: Depth=1
    movl    (%rcx,%rax,4), %esi
    movl    %esi, (%rdx)
    incq    %rax
    cmpq    $10, %rax
    jne LBB0_1
## BB#2:
    popq    %rbp
    ret
```

In this new compiled version, `%esi` is `n`.

---

The way compilers achieve the “lifting variable declaration outside of loop” optimization even at the lowest level of optimization is by lifting the declaration of all block-scope automatic variables to function scope. There is absolutely nothing to it. Also no discussion of compiler optimization makes much sense without minimal understanding of the target language, in which a variable declaration needs not result in any code.